# pandas expanding operation: restriction of window-size for cross-sectional statistics

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I notice a curious behaviour in the `expanding` function of pandas; say I have a simple dataframe:

```
n_rows = 3
n_cols = n_rows+2
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(n_rows,n_cols)))

#my particular df: 
#df = 
#    [[8, 1, 7, 7, 7],
#     [7, 1, 0, 5, 4],
#     [3, 7, 7, 7, 0]]
```

Now I expect the last column of the expanding averaging operation to equal the full cross-sectional mean:

```
pd.concat((df.expanding(axis=1).mean(), 
           df.mean(1).rename('Full mean')),1)

#the output: 
#     0   1        2      3       4     Full mean
#0  8.0 4.5 5.333333    5.0 7.000000    6.0
#1  7.0 4.0 2.666667    2.0 3.000000    3.4
#2  3.0 5.0 5.666667    7.0 4.666667    4.8
```

As we see, the 'Full mean' column does not equal the column id 4. Instead, what we observe is that the max window size for the cross-sectional averaging during the `expanding` operation is limited to `n_rows`.

So, instead of (8+1+7+7+7)/5 in the first line of column id 4, we get (7+7+7)/3 there.

This upper-bounding of the window size can be verified by truncating `df` to a square structure:

```
df_trunc = df.iloc[:, 0:n_rows].copy()
pd.concat((df_trunc.expanding(axis=1).mean(), 
           df_trunc.mean(1).rename('Full mean')),1)

#     0   1        2    Full mean
#0  8.0 4.5 5.333333    5.333333
#1  7.0 4.0 2.666667    2.666667
#2  3.0 5.0 5.666667    5.666667
```

Why is there such an upper bound on the window size to the number of rows, and how does one remove that restriction?

Comment: I can answer the second half of my question, which is a simple workaround: ```df.T.expanding().mean().T```. This gives the correct number of data points in the expanding window. But it does not answer the first half of my question, and whether there is a better way to do this without a transpose.

Comment: For the expanding part(second half), you can use `axis=1` instead of transposing: `df.expanding(axis=1).mean()` for the first part, I am not clear with the requirement.

Comment: @anky That is what I was doing: see my second and third code cells; but the computed values are wrong due to the restriction on the expanding window.